# mui/index/render loading slow, index reindex when I navigate pages in admin

Tags: reindex, indexing, render

A store we look after is experiencing odd behaviour recently.

The admin dashboard is very slow and from what I can figure out, the indexes seem to reindex whenever you navigate to a different page. All indexes are set to Update on Save, which probably doesn't help?

What is the optimal reindex setting?

What is mui/index/render, and what would cause it to load slow?

What can cause the index to reindex when changing page?

Comment: Check if full reindex is triggered programmatically through any bad coding practice. There is no optimal reindex setting, The full reindex for a specific index will get triggered depends on your actions  such a deleting/updating category, updating store view, importing etc

Comment: Looks like the slow loading was fixed by setting bin/magento -n setup:config:set --session-save-redis-disable-locking=1

Still no idea why the reindex was happening, but I changed them to update by schedule anyway

Comment: What did you use for the schedule frequency?

Comment: @WilsonHauck the index schedule is done via the main cron job afaik. The store in question is on Sonassi, who have a tailored cron script that is used.